# Service with API to send JavaScript code to run in a sandbox

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, sandbox, sandbox-solution

I want students to submit JavaScript code to our server. Then we test that JavaScript code to make sure the students solved the problem. I want to test for exceptions thrown, output, what's returned, individual variables and functions that were called.

Is there a service with an API that I can send student submitted JavaScript code along with our tests?

I'm familiar with sandbox JavaScript environments like JSFiddle, but I need an API so our environment can easily test and get results.

Comment: You could github.com to host and use your testing framework on some online CI server like jenkins, travis ci, etc. to see your test results.

Comment: @LukeHutton that's too slow. I need to respond with an answer to the student right away